# Curl website hidden behind loading screen

Tags: bash, scripting, osx, curl

Some websites ([example](http://www9.watchdbs.xyz/)) have a "loading" screen display before they show you their actual content.

[image: http://www9.watchdbs.xyz/]

If I `curl` the site, I get this loading screen rather than the content which I want.

How can a bash program get the actual content of the web page, rather than this "redirecting" page?

Comment: It is VERY hard if not impossible with a bash script by itself, there's a hidden form in the loading page that sends the refresh request to get the actual page, this refresh request has 3 special values that must be submitted, 2 are readily available in the form text, but the 3rd one is dynamically generated by javascript with a bunch of boolean operations, without this dynamic number is impossible to get past the loading page, so unless you use a javascript console or find a way to calculate that number, you are out of luck

Comment: If you are wondering, the dynamic value looks something like this `var SUpHfAR={"OeyIiO":+((+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))}` doing the boolean arithmetic operations results in `17` and more operations of the same kind are processed later, also the associative array name changes each request along with the element name inside the array.